# How to clear DNS cache of internet provider

Tags: caching

I changed the dns of my website and i noticed that it still not applied yet but after awhile I opened my website using VPN from other country and the dns was changed to my new server.

How to clear the local internet cache of the internet provider ?

Answer (score 0):

So, a really good way to check if a DNS is updated globally is to use googles DNS checker tool. You can get to it through this link
https://dns.google.com/

Go to that website and type in the url of your website, and make sure that it has the correct IP address.

If that worked, you can be confident it is a problem with your local cache. You can use the google server dns instead of the default server your computer comes with, which will match the server you just checked with the website.

For WINDOWS 10:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click Network and Internet
3. Click Network and Sharing Center
4. Click Change adapter settings
5. Right-click the network interface connected to the internet and select properties
6. Select and check the internet protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4) option
7. Click the properties button
8. Click use the following DNS server
9. type 8.8.8.8 for preferred and 8.8.4.4 for alternate (these are the addresses to google dns servers, the ones you just checked with the webstite earlier)

For mac:

1. Go to system preferences
2. Select network
3. Click on advanced
4. Select DNS
5. Select the default dns server ip address and click - at the bottom of the DNS servers box
6. Click on the + sign at the bottom on the DNS servers box and enter 
   8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
7. Click ok
8. Click apply

Credit: 
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

https://www.my-private-network.co.uk/kbhome/how-to-set-google-dns-on-your-mac-os-x-computer/

Google is generally very quick in updating their DNS, so it should be more than a few minutes till your server is up and running with the new DNS.